# How to keep a random variable throughout?

Tags: java

I apologize in advance for my English, not my first language.

Brief description of program: Generate random first term in arithmetic sequence and generate random difference to get next term. Then ask user to put in the sixth term.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project{
   static int diff;

   public static int calcSeq(int num){
      return num+diff;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      int diff = (int)(Math.random()*20)+1;
      int term1 = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
      int sum = term1;
      int ans = 0;

      System.out.println(term1);

      for (int i = 1; i<=4; i=i+1){
         int nextTerm = calcSeq(term1);
         sum = sum + nextTerm;

         System.out.println(sum);
      }

      int term6 = sum + diff;
      System.out.println(term6);
      System.out.print("Enter the sixth term of this arithmetic sequence: ");
      ans = keyboard.nextInt();

      if (ans == term6){
         System.out.println("That is the correct answer.");
      }
      else if (ans != term6){
         System.out.println("That is incorrect. Try again.");
      }
   }
}
```

For the first five terms the difference remains the same and is correct arithmetic sequence. But then when get to sixth term the difference changes and the sequence is no longer correct. For example correct sequence could be 2,4,6,8,10,12. Here the difference is 2. But when the program runs it goes like 2,4,6,8,10,15 which is not correct. So my question is how to keep the random difference constant throughout?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are conflicting your `diff` variables. One is static, `Project.diff` and the other is local, `diff`. The one in `calcSeq` will always use the static one, which is 0. The one under your for loop might be using the local, random `diff` under your `keyboard` variable assignment. To make them the same reference, remove `int` from in front of the second `diff` and just do `diff = Math.random...`

**Update**
I am not entirely convinced you need the `calcSeq` method at all. Your code can be simplified down and acheive what you are trying to accomplish. For example, you are printing `term6`, then asking to input `term6`, so you never get an incorrect answer if you enter the last number. The logic or your code is (1)  Get a random start and a random difference (2) Print out the sequence, adding `diff` each time (3) Prompt the user for the next answer. This code does just that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project{
   static int diff = 0;

   public static int printSequence(int start, int length){
      System.out.println(start);
      for (int i = 1; i <= length; i=i+1){
         start = start + diff;
         System.out.println(start);
      }
      return start;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      diff = (int)(Math.random()*20)+1;
      int term1 = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;

      int term6 = printSequence(term1, 4) + diff;

      System.out.print("Enter the sixth term of this arithmetic sequence: ");
      int ans = keyboard.nextInt();

      if (ans == term6){
         System.out.println("That is the correct answer.");
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("That is incorrect. Try again.");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new beginner to java and programming could you explain a little more simpler?

Comment: I think what you're trying to tell me is that the second int diff is conflicting with the first so I should remove the int to make them the same? But I just tried doing that and still have the same problem the sixth term is using a different random difference

Comment: Normally you would be right but this is for a class project and one of the requirements is to include at least one custom method. So unfortunately I wouldn't be able to use your code. Any other ideas?

Comment: @kidGil - So `diff` wasn't the problem. The problem is `calcSeq(term1)` was always using `term1` as the parameter and `term1` was never changing. If you need a custom method, though. I will update again.

Comment: So you're saying the problem is with the custom method?

Comment: Well I ran your code and it worked so thanks a lot! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: The problem was that you were always adding "`term2`" (`term1` + `diff`) to each `sum` then at the end you added `diff`. For example. `term1 = 1`, `diff = 8`. Your original code prints `1 10 19 28 37`. A human thinks `37 + 9 = 46`, but your code was expecting `37 + diff = 37 + 8 = 45`. You're welcome anyways, though, @kidGil.